# syntax error in python with arrays and for loop with if elif?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, syntax

this my calibration code in python. i have 16 analog sensors connected to my raspberry pi 2,
GPIOs 7, 11, 13, 15 control a 16 to 1 multiplexer and i feed the analog signals to an MCP3002 to have them read by my raspberry.
i know that this code works because until the time that i had the calibration code writen everything went smooth. but just because i have diferent number of readings from each sensor a single number as a threshold is not enough.
so i created 2 arrays of integers and a for loop to pass through every sensor,
read it three times and get the average price and store it to calibration_max array. then print a message and give you 3 seconds before it goes and do the same thing for this sensor so it can go and store the min value that can get from this sensor and store it to the calibration_min array so i can use it as reference for my threshold.

but i get this error message every time i go and compile it to the shell.

there is an error to your program:
unindent does not match any outer indentation level

why do i get this error message ?

```
calibration_max=array.array('i',(0 for m in range(0,16)))
calibration_min=array.array('i',(0 for n in range(0,16)))
for m in range(0, 16):
    x == m
    if x == 0:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 1:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 2:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 3:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 4:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 5:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 6:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 7:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 0)
        elif x == 8:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 9:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 10:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 11:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 0)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 12:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 13:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 0)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 14:
            GPIO.output(7, 0)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
        elif x == 15:
            GPIO.output(7, 1)
            GPIO.output(11, 1)
            GPIO.output(13, 1)
            GPIO.output(15, 1)
    # average three readings to get a more stable one
    channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
    calibration_max(m) == channeldata
    print("place magnet over sensor No:"(n+1))
    sleep(3)
    # average three readings to get a more stable one
    channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
    calibration_min(n) == channeldata
    n=n+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have different indention levels for the first `if` and the following `elif`. This is a problem since python defines blocks by indention level.

Try this:

```
calibration_max=array.array('i',(0 for m in range(0,16)))
calibration_min=array.array('i',(0 for n in range(0,16)))
for m in range(0, 16):
    x == m
    if x == 0:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 1:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 2:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 3:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 4:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 5:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 6:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 7:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 0)
    elif x == 8:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 9:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 10:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 11:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 12:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 13:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 0)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 14:
        GPIO.output(7, 0)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    elif x == 15:
        GPIO.output(7, 1)
        GPIO.output(11, 1)
        GPIO.output(13, 1)
        GPIO.output(15, 1)
    # average three readings to get a more stable one
    channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
    calibration_max(m) == channeldata
    print("place magnet over sensor No:"(n+1))
    sleep(3)
    # average three readings to get a more stable one
    channeldata_1 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_2 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    sleep(0.001)
    channeldata_3 = read_mcp3002(0) # get CH0 input
    channeldata = (channeldata_1+channeldata_2+channeldata_3)/3
    calibration_min(n) == channeldata
    n=n+1
```

Comment: it actually works ! thanks ! i am not good at all with python. now i get an error message about array declaration. how do i declare an array in python ?

Comment: this is what i get in to my terminal :  File "./Documents/Examples/spitest2.py", line 91, in <module>
    calibration_max=array.array('i',(0 for m in range(0,16)))
NameError: name 'array' is not defined

Comment: You're probalby missing an `import array` at the top of your file. This imports the module containing the definition of python arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Code blocks in Python are defined by their indentation, therefore 'elif' indentation should match 'if' indentation:

```
if x == 0:
...
elif x == 1:
...
elif x == 2:
...
```